# J programming how to wait fo X seconds before executing the next verb?

Tags: while-loop, j

I want to wait for X seconds before executing the next line in a verb.
So far, I have tried this foreign command `6!:3 (2.5)` found in [time (delay)](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx006.htm) though it looks like the entire verb execution is delayed instead of only delaying the execution of the next line.
I want to use this inside a while loop.
Example:

```
while. T do.
  verb1''
  verb2''
  wait for X seconds
end.
```

Whay am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are doing anything wrong and I think that your program is delaying line by line, even though it looks like it is holding up the execution of the whole verb.

```
 t=: 3 : 0
echo '1';6!:0 '' NB. timestamp
6!:3 (2.5)
echo '2';6!:0 ''
6!:3 (2.5)
echo '3';6!:0 ''
)
    
       t ''
┌─┬──────────────────────┐
│1│2021 1 1 12 24 19.7376│
└─┴──────────────────────┘
┌─┬──────────────────────┐
│2│2021 1 1 12 24 22.2398│
└─┴──────────────────────┘
┌─┬──────────────────────┐
│3│2021 1 1 12 24 24.7418│
└─┴──────────────────────┘
```

When I ran the verb it did result in about a 5 second delay before I saw the results, but it looks like the lines actually ran at the appropriate time.

Comment: Bob your example is enlightening although it showes an unexpected behaviour! What I would like to achieve is to echo each line one after the other at the end of the wait time and not having the whole result deplayed in one shot. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe look at the lab format? https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Labs/Index It doesn't allow you to break down verbs line by line except if you put them into a lab a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior discussed here is actually only observed in jqt, and it happens due to buffered I/O between the J process that's actually executing your code and the GUI process that displays it.

In jconsole, jhs, and even on Android, the following code displays 2, waits 2.5 seconds, and then displays 1:

```
lag =: 6!:3 bind 2.5
echo 1 [ lag '' [ echo 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. But, as Julian noted, the I/O is buffered, and JQT will only print output when control is returned, unless you use wd'msgs'. This works:

```
NB. sleep after flushing I/O when running JQt
sleep =: 6!:3@(][ ([:wd'msgs'"_)^:IFQT)

foo =: 3 : 0
  for. i. 5 do.
  echo 'hello'
  sleep 1
end.
)
foo''
```